# Take Unique id and use as url for page

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am building a website for sharing links and pictures for php experience. Currently, each post has a page where users can comment on it. Every post also has an id that is stored in a database with it. What would be the easiest way to make this id the url of the post? For example:
For the question that has an id of 4a3cd5, I would want the url for that question to be post.com/posts.php/4a3cd5. thanks for your answers.

Comment: well that includes some HTACCESS routing... I'd suggest for the time being using it in the form of posts.php?id=4a3cd5 . Do you want cod for the htaccess routing or the php code that can parse that kind of url structure ?

Comment: I'm not sure that i need that, I'm just using localhost right now. I think it's set up for that

Comment: ... nothing is set up in the way that you showed by default, although it looks similar to code igniter...

Answer (score 1):

In the HTAccess page (`.htaccess`), write the following code:-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/$ /posts.php?id=$1
```

So now, in the Address Space, if you write `http://localhost/posts/4a3cd5`, the user will be shown a page corresponding to the post ID of `4a3cd5`. Internally, the URL which will get processed is this one `http://localhost/posts.php?id=4a3cd5`. This whole technique is being done by [HTAccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess), and this way of showing URLs to users is called [SEF URLs](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/search-engine-friendly-urls).
More on the HTAccess tips & tricks can be found [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php).

Now in the page "`posts.php`", you can write all the logic which you want using the PHP GET [Superglobal Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) "`$_GET['id']`".

**NP:** A special note - please try to avoid this type of coding. Instead try using any of the available standard [PHP MVC Frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

That would involve a lot, maybe you should just have URL's like `/posts.php/?post=4a3cd5`.

Overall this would be much more practical. You can just `GET` the post variable and connect to your SQL database.

Comment: How does Stackoverflow do this? They have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532392/take-unique-id-and-use-as-url-for-page

Comment: How would you write php code to make the form create a page with a unique number and the question in the url?

Comment: okay i have it so that the url for the post contains all of the post data and the id, how do i shorten it so that its just the id in the url? right now it looks like: (answers.php/4d98ee65ca55e?name=hahaha&question=BLeh&id=4d98ee65ca55e&datafile=)

Comment: @jajaja You just need the post ID in the URL. Then use a code like this:

`<?php 
 $post_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['post_id']) // get id from url
 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email='$email'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $question = $row['question'];
    // etc etc
 }

 ?>`

Then just echo all the retrieved values.

Basically I would just store all the questions in a MySQL database and url the question unique id to retrieve the question.